# Pointers to Structs Implementation of Stack Data Structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

I've created a Stack structure in C.  When the stack is initialized with a value, I am able to print it back and receive the correct output. However, after pushing a new string, the print function prints what appears to be a random character (ASCII 177).

Originally, I implemented this project with pointers, but I was unable to get it working.  Instead, I opted to only use a pointer for the `Node *nodes` member of `Stack`.  That way, when I need to grow the stack, I can just multiply the amount of memory required by `Stack.size`.  However, this approach has not worked yet either.

```
#define MAX_DATA 64
struct Node{
    char val[MAX_DATA];
};

struct Stack{
    int size;
    struct Node *nodes;
};
```

These are used as follows:

```
struct Node node = {.val = "Test"};
struct Stack stack = newStack(node);
printStack(stack);
```

The `newStack` function initializes `nodes` properly.  For the sake of inclusion:

```
struct Stack newStack(struct Node node)
{
    struct Stack stack;
    stack.size = 1;
    stack.nodes = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    stack.nodes[0] = node;
    return stack;
}
```

The stack is then printed iteratively in `printStack()`, with `stack.size` being the upper bound of the for-loop.

The trouble comes when I try to run:

```
struct Node node2 = {.val = "Test1"};
push(stack, node2);
printStack(stack);
```

The push function aims to create a temporary stack and assign the value of the stack to it.  After this, the `size` is incremented, the pointer to the `nodes` is freed, and new memory is allocated, with room for a new member at the end.

```
void push(struct Stack stack, struct Node node)
{
    struct Stack temp_stack = stack;
    stack.size += 1;
    free(stack.nodes);
    stack.nodes = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node) * stack.size);
    for(int i = 0; i < temp_stack.size; i++){
        stack.nodes[i] = temp_stack.nodes[i];
    }
    stack.nodes[stack.size - 1] = node;
}
```

Needless to say, this doesn't execute properly.

The expected output would be:

```
Test
Test1
```

But, instead, I receive only ASCII-177.  It is also worth noting that the execution hangs after it prints that and moves to the new line.  This results in `Aborted (core dumped)`.

Am I improperly freeing and re-allocating memory?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth remembering that in C, passing a struct to a function is *pass-by-value*, i.e.,  the function gets a *copy* of the struct. All members of the struct, including pointer variables (but not whatever the pointer references), are duplicated.

So in the push function, think about what happens to the original when you modify this copy (e.g., `stack.size += 1`, and also when you `free()` the stack.nodes.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Is there a way in C to have a function be a "member" of a struct instead?  Google told me no, but I figured I'd ask.  I will also try passing the stack as a pointer.  Thank you again

Comment: Not really, as you've discovered.  A struct member can be a _function pointer_, but that doesn't help much because C isn't object-oriented and thus has no concept of `this` or `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to `peekay` for the recommendations.  I ended up doing a re-write.  It became quite a bit simpler.  I did remove a layer of "visibility" by storing the nodes as a pointer, but I suppose this implementation is a bit more true to the data structure.

Node is implemented as a means to hold data, and the user doesn't interact with it directly.  It also points to the following Node.  Stack is implemented to hold the top Node, and also the size of the Stack.

Node:

```
struct Node{
    char val[MAX_DATA];
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Stack:

```
struct Stack{
    struct Node *top;
    int size;
};
```

Push:

```
void push(struct Stack *stack, char *newVal)
{
    struct Node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    strcpy(newNode->val, newVal);
    newNode->next = stack->top;
    stack->top = newNode;
    stack->size++;
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Stack stack;
newStack(&stack);

push(&stack, "Test");
push(&stack, "Test1");
push(&stack, "Test2");
push(&stack, "Test3");
```

[Complete Code](https://pastebin.com/meckjaEW)

[Updated, accessible Nodes](https://pastebin.com/2eqLRjiH)

Comment: Worth checking having `malloc()` with no corresponding `free()`.  They should be paired, as otherwise you'd have a memory leak.  Unlike C++, C doesn't have real _pass-by-reference_ so passing pointer values are common.

Comment: I had a free statement in there before posting, but that caused the same issues as originally posted.  I tried to instead create a copy of the stack in `temp_stack`, then free the stack's nodes pointer, but it ended up doing the same.

Comment: Problems with `free()` generally fall into three buckets: 1) calling it too early (while the memory is still in use); 2) calling it twice; or 3) not calling it at all.  I think your code probably went from 1) to 3) (and possibly back to 1).

Comment: As evidenced by the fact that I'm once again facing errors.  But, I'm working on a more efficient solution overall.  Thank you

Comment: Nice, the code has evolved a lot.  Sometimes when working on something like this is useful to think of your Stacks and Nodes are two somewhat separable entities.  So far, it is not possible to create a Node outside of a stack.  It might be nice from an API perspective to be able to create Nodes (without a stack), create a new empty Stack, push the Nodes to the (empty) Stack, pop them from the stack, then destroy the nodes & the stack -- independently.  It might be interesting to have  createStack() and createNode() functions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely keep adding to it!  It'll certainly be handy to have the code implemented going forward.  C seems to be more interesting than I gave it credit for.